# Keras AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, jupyter-notebook

I'm running a Keras neural network model in Jupyter Notebook (Python 3.6)

I get the following error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'

after calling the .fit() method from Keras.model

```
model  = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=len(X_data[0]), activation='sigmoid' ))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(X_data, y_data, epochs=20, batch_size=10)
```

I checked the requirements.txt file for Keras (in Anaconda3) and the numpy, scipy, and six module versions are all up to date.

What can explain this AttributeError?

The full error message is the following (seems to be somewhat related to Numpy):

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         3 model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
>         4 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
>   ----> 5 model.fit(X_data, y_data, epochs=20, batch_size=10)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in fit(self, x, y,
>   batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split,
>   validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch,
>   steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
>       963                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
>       964                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
>   --> 965                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
>       966 
>       967     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x,
>   y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split,
>   validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch,
>   steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)    1591
>   class_weight=class_weight,    1592             check_batch_axis=False,
>   -> 1593             batch_size=batch_size)    1594         # Prepare validation data.    1595         do_validation = False
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in
>   _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_batch_axis, batch_size)    1424
>   self._feed_input_shapes,    1425
>   check_batch_axis=False,
>   -> 1426                                     exception_prefix='input')    1427         y = _standardize_input_data(y, self._feed_output_names,
>   1428                                     output_shapes,
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in
>   _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
>        68     elif isinstance(data, list):
>        69         data = [x.values if x.**class**.**name** == 'DataFrame' else x for x in data]
>   ---> 70         data = [np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data]
>        71     else:
>        72         data = data.values if data.**class**.**name** == 'DataFrame' else data
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in
>   (.0)
>        68     elif isinstance(data, list):
>        69         data = [x.values if x.**class**.**name** == 'DataFrame' else x for x in data]
>   ---> 70         data = [np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data]
>        71     else:
>        72         data = data.values if data.**class**.**name** == 'DataFrame' else data
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`model.fit` expects **x** and **y** to be numpy array. Seems like you pass a list, it tried to get shape of input by reading `ndim` attribute of numpy array and failed.

You can simply transform it using `np.array`:

```
import numpy as np
...
model.fit(np.array(train_X),np.array(train_Y), epochs=20, batch_size=10)
```

Comment: that was the problem. Fixed it! Funny though, since on another computer Keras could run even if the data was a double matrix instead of a numpy array. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

When you import you should use `tensorflow.keras` instead of just `keras` like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense
```

because there is a bug related to the `keras` module.

Reference: [here](https://gist.github.com/datlife/abfe263803691a8864b7a2d4f87c4ab8).

Comment: Is this for tensorflow 2.x?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the shape of your training data but I suspect that you have an error on your `input_dim`. Try changing it to `input_dim=len(X_data)` like this:

```
model  = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=len(X_data), activation='sigmoid' ))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(X_data, y_data, epochs=20, batch_size=10)
```

Comment: the X_data has 5 features and the y_data has 2 features. The output data might have been the cause, though switching to a numpy array solves the problem.