# 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim' error while making 3dplots

Tags: python

I was trying to construct `3dplots` in `python` from a tutorial but as I run my code from the editor it shows up this error `"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'"`. What could be possibly wrong in my code, which is shown below? I appreciate your support.

Code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   fig=plt.figure()
   chart= fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection='3d')

   X,Y,Z=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[2,5,3,8,9,5,6,1],[3,6,2,7,5,4,5,6]
   chart.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)

   plt.show()
```

Comment: `ndim` is a method used on `numpy` arrays. You have defined regular python lists. `import numpy as np; X,Y,Z=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),np.array([2,5,3,8,9,5,6,1]),np.array([3,6,2,7,5,4,5,6])`. Does that work?

Comment: Turns out your question is an exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225830/axes3d-plot-wireframex-y-z-error). My suggestion does fix your initial issue but then you will get `ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.`. None of the answers there are accepted or upvoted though, so it can't be used as a dupe. I suggest you upvote an answer there if it fixes your issue. Also, `ndim` is an attribute, not a method, sorry.

Comment: Tried your method @roganjosh. Getting the same error as you mentioned. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The similar problem has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65037237/valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-7-1-into-shape-7

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @roganjosh, the error that your are having is because the method is expecting a `numpy` array. Applying @roganjosh's suggestions to your code will look like this:

```
import numpy as np # you need this import to create a numpy array.
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure()
chart= fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection='3d')

# The following line was changed:
X,Y,Z = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),np.array([2,5,3,8,9,5,6,1]),np.array([3,6,2,7,5,4,5,6])

chart.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```

Another questions which has a similar problem is this one:  [Keras AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493755/keras-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-ndim)