# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (7,1) into shape (7)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I have a output called `summation` of the following form :

```
[[0.02719706]
 [0.02851958]
 [0.03727741]
 [0.03857162]
 [0.02222067]
 [0.06348368]
 [0.0179843 ]]
```

The output `summation` changes with loop `j`.
At each loop `j`, I am looking to store this result in a matrix `MatrixDimension=np.zeros(( 7 , country ))`

```
country=4
for j in range(country):       
     for i in range(7):
            xxxxxxx
            # code depends on j and i
            xxxxxxx
            summation[i]=np.sum(temp)    
     MatrixDimension[:, j]= summation  ## where i have error
```

I get an error as follows

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (7,1) into shape (7)
```

How can i fix this please?

Comment: Your code as written here is not functional, but anyways, the problem lies (as the error states) in the different shape of your arrays. For a quick fix, use `MatrixDimension[:,j] = np.squeeze(sumation)`.
It would be helpful for you to read some [Numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) :)

Comment: Thank you. I was about to do np.squeeze() :)    Why not functional?

Comment: Sorry, by "not functional" I mean that I can't run it in a Python terminal as it is presented in your question. To make SO's users life easier, it is recommended to write a Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE) of your code, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why is `summation` shape (7,1) to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether *summation* is a **1-D** array.

In this case the following code:

```
country = 4
MatrixDimension = np.zeros((7, country))
summation = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13])
j = 0
MatrixDimension[:, j] = summation
print(MatrixDimension)
```

runs without any error and yields:

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 5.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 7.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 9.  0.  0.  0.]
 [11.  0.  0.  0.]
 [13.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

But if the source array is a **column** array, e.g.:

```
xx = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13])[..., None]
```

then an attempt to execute e.g. `MatrixDimension[:, 2] = xx`
raises just the same exception which you mentioned, as
`xx.shape` is *(7, 1)*, i.e. it is a **2-D** array.

Answer (score 1):

```
 MatrixDimension[:, j:j+1] = summation
```

can put 2D array into the Matrix